# Wakanda server side timeout?

Tags: javascript, server, timeout, ssjs, wakanda

Wakanda 1.0.3 OS X.

Question:  I have a long running process on the server side, which is called on the server side.  It could run as long as 4-5 minutes.  What are the limits for Wakanda Server in terms of how long a SSJS will wait before it times out waiting for the response from the ds method?

Kirk

Comment: Are you currently seeing an issue with your long running method or are you just curious? Does it include any data access? If it has data access is the datastore local or remote (like 4d-mobile) to the wakanda server?

Answer (score 0):

There is no time limits for wakanda server processing or for a response from ds methods.
I just created a dataClass method with an infinite loop . After more than 15 minutes, the server is still processing.

Walid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a Wakanda Cloud instance there is a 120 second timeout unless you utilize a process in the background and create a new method to check the process status that will be returning 202 if the process is still running and finally 200 when it's done.